# Veeam Backup To Tape Scenario

Tags: virtual-machine, vsphere, backup-strategies, retention, veeam

Hi sorry for my limitations in English I made this question using google translate, I hope you understand what I mean.

I have 20 jobs that have 7 days of retention. I plan to extend my retention to 30 days, but the size of my repository is very limited so storing 30 restore points on a local disk is not possible. that's why I plan to use tape to extend my retention

this is the model i want:

**- Restore points days -1 to -7 are stored locally**

**- Restore points for days -8 to -30 are stored in tape.**

Can anyone give me some advice, because I am very new to Veeam

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario which you would like to deploy doesn't end up in the result to try achieve. VBR isn't able to store backups on tape directly. You can only copy backups to tape, but has to be written on disk first.

My advice is to create a scale-out repository which can be extended to the cloud if it this is suitable for you.

I hope my answer helps a little bit.

Greetings,
Chris